# unzip multiple files using Python and set each included file as a new variable

Tags: python, zip

I have a zip file that contains 2 files.  I need to set each filename within the zip as a different variable.  But I'm not sure how to do that.

The following code will extract both files, and will list both filenames,  but for the life of me I can only get the variable to set on the last extracted file.

Here is a link to a test .zip with 2 files.  One file is "a", and the other file is "b.txt":  http://www.fileconvoy.com/dfl.php?id=g676b9e355f65d84d9999232466917f2b06cc5d45e

The output I'm looking for is:

```
filename1 = a
filename2 = b.txt
```

I'm not sure how to do that though.  Here is my code.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
outpath = '/home/ubuntu/untitled/'
fn = 'myzipfile.zip'

import zipfile

fh = open(fn, 'rb')
z = zipfile.ZipFile(fh)

for name in z.namelist():
    z.extract(name, outpath)
fh.close()

file = zipfile.ZipFile(fn, "r")
for info in file.infolist():
    print info.filename
    filename = info.filename

print "Extracted Filename: " + filename



> a
> b.txt
> Extracted Filename b.txt
```

Can anyone show me how to create an incrementing variable name  --- because if I get a .zip that has 3 files, I'd like it to be filename1, filename2, filename3?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by using **[`shutil.copyfileobj`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/shutil.html#shutil.copyfileobj)** to copy extracted file object to a file with whatever name you want it to be.

```
import zipfile
import shutil

with zipfile.ZipFile('file_test.zip', 'r') as myfile:
    target_names = ['filename1.txt', 'filename2.txt'] # names you want it to be

    for item, name in zip(myfile.infolist(), target_names):
        shutil.copyfileobj(myfile.open(item), open(name, 'w')) # copy extracted file object to a desired file
        print 'The original file %s in zip file is now extracted and renamed to %s' % (item.filename, name)
```